# change the state of toggle on correct password and dismiss the dialog

Tags: android

In my application,I need to off the toggle if password is correct else it should be on always.
I am showing a dialog box for asking password on setOnCheckedChangeListener,
and change the state of toggle if  password is correct.

My problem is 
as soon as the toggle changes its state it shows the dialog again.
dialog should dismiss if the password is correct ,same time the state of toggle should change to off.
How to solve this.

My code:

```
    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {          @Override           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked)              
{
                                 if(isCorrectPin)
                {
                    onOffSwitch.setChecked(false);
                }

                    Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
                    if(isChecked)
                    {  
                        //tv_switch_status.setText("");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        displayPinAlert();

                    }           }       

            });

    private void displayPinAlert()
    {   
    onOffSwitch.setChecked(true);


        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.getParent());


        alert.setMessage("Enter Pin");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input   
       final EditText input = new EditText(activity.getParent());   
       alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)    
                 {          
                 String value = input.getText().toString();
                            //              

                  onOffSwitch.setChecked(false);            
                  // Do something with value!            
                  if(value.equals("1234"))          {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //onOffSwitch.setChecked(false);
                                isCorrectPin =true;

                }
                    }   });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {          // Canceled.        }   });

        alert.show();


    }
```

Comment: I want to dismiss the dialog , and change the state of toggle to off ,if password is correct

Comment: and your code don't work? crash?

Comment: no it is working but it leaves the dialog on if the password is correct

Answer (score 0):

Change your displayPinAlert to this:

```
private void displayPinAlert()
{   
onOffSwitch.setChecked(true);


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.getParent());


    alert.setMessage("Enter Pin");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input   
   final EditText input = new EditText(activity.getParent());   
   alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)    
             {          
             String value = input.getText().toString();
                        //              

              onOffSwitch.setChecked(false);            
              // Do something with value!            
              if(value.equals("1234"))          {

                dialog.dismiss();
                onOffSwitch.setChecked(false);

            }
                }   });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {          // Canceled.        }   });

    dialog = alert.show();

}
```

The problem is caused by the fact you dismiss a old reference of a dialog, not the last created.

Comment: it is not working , dialog dismissed but it reopen because it change the state of toggle

Comment: use a boolean variable to block the setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Or set the listener to null (setOnChdckedChangeListener (null);)

Comment: How it will help , I have tried to use boolean but that is not working

Comment: Can you post the updated code? I think the problem is caused by the fact that setSelected call the listener.